# Flink program getting unresponsive suddenly

Tags: apache-flink

We have a Flink application with the following architecture:
Kafka producers >> Send data to Kakfa topic >> Flink program subscribed to Kafka topic >> Data process and send processed data to ElastcSearch.

Few days ago we encountered strange problem on the Flink servers deployed on Production environment. The Flink program suddenly stopped to respond(there were no logs being output at all), niether any data was being saved in ElastcSearch. Data from the Kafka producers was reaching properly to the Kafka topic as confirmed from the Kafka logs, but seemingly they were not getting sent to Flink for some reason. We are guessing that there might have developed some connection issues between the Flink and EC2 instances(although could not get any trace of any connection terminated logs..).

Can somebody please hint on any other possible reasons for the Flink getting suddenly unresponsive or on how to debug on this issue more deeply(looking at some specific Flink/Kafka system logs etc) ?

1. Flink configuration is of a 3 node cluster with 2 master nodes and 3 task nodes(logs were not output on any of the 3 nodes).
2. CPU and memory consumption were within normal limits on all the 3 nodes, no sudden spikes or so.
3. Not sure whether this has a relation with the above problem or not but around 3 minutes before the Flink became unresponsive, there was an '429 Too Many requests' error while saving some data on the ElasticSearch. But this error came only once and a few seconds later, data again started getting saved in ElasticSearch without any errors.

```
2023-05-30 17:43:13,075 ERROR org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkBase  - Failed Elasticsearch bulk request: Unable to parse response body
ElasticsearchStatusException[Unable to parse response body]; nested: ResponseException[method [POST], host [https://****], URI [/_bulk?timeout=1m], status line [HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests]
429 Too Many Requests /_bulk];
```

4. After digging around the problem for around 30 mins, being not able to exact root cause, the Flink Job was just resubmitted and then everything started working fine.

Comment: Based on the ElasticSearch log, I'm wondering if the ElasticSearch sink wasn't able to keep up with the amount of writes that were happening. In case you have metrics logged, it would be interesting to see if there's backpressure happening somewhere in one of your operators. If so, that could be an indicator of Flink slowing down processing, which might be mistaken for hanging.